# groovy script binding does not seem to operate

Tags: groovy

though I like Groovy sometimes the documentation is ... well terse

I have a problem to pass a binding to a script.

here is the code :

```
def conf = new CompilerConfiguration()
Binding env = new Binding()
//....
env.setProperty( // some key and value set
//
conf.setScriptBaseClass(// name of class that is a Script
def shell = new GroovyShell(env,conf)
//isReader is the reader of the code// argz is an array of Strings
 shell.run(isReader, scriptName, argz)
```

well, for one, the "scriptname" parameter in "run" is an obscure feature (any hint? -the reader does not have the notion of a file-)

then the Binding I get in my script instance is different from the one I created! (so unable to pass variables back and forth)

I need to invoke my script using my script base class and pass a Binding and parameters to it ... if there is another way that works I would be delighted! thanks!

edit ... trying to set up examples :

```
package abcgroovy
abstract class MyScript  extends Script{
MyScript() {
    super()
    def _env = getBinding()
    println _env
}

    MyScript(Binding binding) {
        super(binding)
        def _env = binding
        println _env
    }
}
```

then the invoking code :

```
def conf = new CompilerConfiguration()
Binding env = new Binding()
println "ENV calling :$env"
conf.setScriptBaseClass("abcgroovy.MyScript")
def shell = new GroovyShell(env,conf)
Reader isReader = new StringReader("println 'hello world'")
// second argument: can't guess what to put
shell.run(isReader,'abcgroovy.MyScript',new String[0])
```

now the result of a run :

```
ENV calling :groovy.lang.Binding@67a20f67
groovy.lang.Binding@6a192cfe
hello world
```

Comment: Why don't you provide a runnable example? And if documentation is terse, maybe issue a pull request with a corrected version?

Comment: a Runnable example will be very long: I'll have to explain how I get hold of the Reader and cite the Script class. I think this will obscure the question. By reading the soruce code it looks like the problem comes from the "scriptname" parameter: I haven't the slightest idea of what this parameter means !

Comment: ok let's try examples :

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Answer (score 0):

1. From my understanding the second parameters (`fileName`) is the name of the file that is parsed. This has no relevance to any functionality, but is used for error reporting. So if you have an error in your provided script, the `fileName` will be used in the error message. Thus, when using a different signature where you provide a `URI` or a `File` that parameter cannot be specified.
2. In your example the `Binding` from the GroovyShell actually *is* used, which you can verify by printing the `Binding` in the actual script.

   ```
   def conf = new CompilerConfiguration()
   Binding env = new Binding()
   println "ENV calling :$env"
   conf.setScriptBaseClass("abcgroovy.MyScript")
   def shell = new GroovyShell(env,conf)
   Reader isReader = new StringReader('println "binding in script: ${getBinding()}"')
   shell.run(isReader,'abcgroovy.MyScript',new String[0])
   ```

The reason your example outputs a different `Binding` is the way the script is initialized. First a new `MyScript` instance is created without passing the `Binding`, then the `Binding` from the `GroovyShell` is set using `setBinding`. The constructor with the `Binding` parameter is not used.

```
abstract class MyScript  extends Script {
    MyScript() {
        super()
        println "MyScript() with binding ${getBinding()}"
    }

    MyScript(Binding binding) {
        super(binding)
        // not invoked!
        println "MyScript(${binding})"
    }

    public void setBinding(Binding binding) {
        super.setBinding(binding)
        println "setBinding to ${binding}"
    }
}
```

**Example output**

```
ENV calling :groovy.lang.Binding@335eadca
MyScript() with binding groovy.lang.Binding@45018215
setBinding to groovy.lang.Binding@335eadca
binding in script: groovy.lang.Binding@335eadca
```

Note that the Binding is temporarily different in the `MyScript()` constructor only.